# how to popup an alert when form is submitted

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a registration form and when people compile the form and submit it I want to show a popup, but the problem is it's not working. here is the code:

```
<?php
    // result is when it's all good
    if ($result) {
        echo '<div class="vai-accedi">
                <div class="vai-accedi2">
                    <div class="vai-accedi3">
                        <p>Congratulazioni! Registrazione Completata, puoi procedere ad accedere al tuo account. clicca ok per procedere</p>
                        <a href="catalogo-prodotti.php">Ok</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
    }
?>
```

All the code

```
<!-- signup backend connection  -->
<?php

include 'dbcon.php';

session_start();
// error_reporting(0);


// if (isset($_SESSION['nome'])) {
//     header("Location: header.php");
// }
  

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['nome']);
    $cvn = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['cittàvn°']);
    $numerodicell = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['numerodicell']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
    $confpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['confpassword']);
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $confpassword = md5($_POST['confpassword']);


    if ($password == $confpassword) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE email='$email'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (!$result->num_rows > 0) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO utenti (nome,cittàvn°, numerodicell, email, password, confpassword)
                    VALUES ('$nome','$cvn','$numerodicell','$email','$password','$confpassword')";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if ($result) {
                // echo "<script>alert('Congratulazioni! Registrazione Completata, puoi procedere ad accedere al tuo account. clicca ok per procedere')</script>";
                echo '<div class="vai-accedi">
            <div class="vai-accedi2">
                <div class="vai-accedi3">

                    
                    <p>Congratulazioni! Registrazione Completata, puoi procedere ad accedere al tuo account. clicca ok per procedere</p>

                    <a href="catalogo-prodotti.php">Ok</a>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>';
            
                // header( "Refresh:1; url='login.php'");
                
                $nome = "";
                $cvn = "";
                $numerodicell = "";
                $email = "";
                $_POST['password'] = "";
                $_POST['confpassword'] = "";
            } else {
                echo "<script>alert('oops! qualcosa è andato storto.')</script>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('oops! Email già registrata.')</script>";
        }
        
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('le due password non combaciano.')</script>";
    }
}

?>      
<!-- signup backend connection  -->


    <div class="registrati">
        <div class="registratiinner registratiinner2">

            <h1>Registrati</h1>
            <form action="" class="sign-up-form" method="POST" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="input-wrapper">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Citta,Via,n°" required  name="cittàvn°">
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Numero di Cellulare" required  name="numerodicell">
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required  name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Crea una Nuova Password" required  name="password">
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Conferma Password" required  name="confpassword">
            </div>
            <div class="accetti">
                <p style="font-size: 1.8rem; margin-top: 0;">Inviando accetti <a href="#">Termini & Condizioni</a></p>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="contact-button" style="border-radius: .5rem;" name="submit" type="submit">Registrati</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: could you please post your submit function?

Comment: You have not use any pop-up or alert in your result success condition. That's why it is just showing plain text on webpage. Or maybe you have written that but shared here. Please post that as well.

Comment: @RamishaMukhtar it's not showing anything, it has tho show the .vai-accedi class that i have edited in abslute position with a black background and the people has to click ok and get ridirect in an another page. that is not working. it's not showing .vai-accedi on form submitted

Comment: So what is `$result`? How is it populated? What does it contain? Does any CSS hide the elements? Have you checked if the HTML gets outputted in the source (by right click on the page and "View page source")? There are too many unknowns here.

Comment: tis is -vai-accedi css '''    .vai-accedi{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        /* display: none; */
        
    } '''

Comment: but is useless because it is not showing anything